# can we have variable size array at arduino?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following variables:

```
char* words[20];
char* tracks[20];
```

where they represent the number of tracks and words saved in a database on a SD card. My question is that, I would like the array of words and tracks to be of variable size and not static, that it is I don't want to specify the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [Standard C++ for Arduino](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus/blob/master/README.md) It lets you use [STL (standard template library)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) [vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_%28C++%29#Vector)